# Sorting list of hex values in Python

Tags: python, sorting, hex

Surprisingly I was not able to find much online. I have a list of hex values, e.g.:

```
hex = ['0x1', '0x2', '0x10', '0x7', '0x1a']
```

that is initially unsorted. If I try to sort it via the `sort()` method on the list it obviously sorts it as a string, not an integer. Is there a simple way to sort this list, ideally without external libraries?

I think the sort function should look something like this:

```
def hex_sort(a, b):
    a = int(a, 0)
    b = int(b, 0)
    return b - a
```

however I had not found a way to pass this function to the `sort()` one. I am not very experienced with python (3.8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter to the `sort` or `sorted` function:

```
hex_list.sort(key=lambda h: int(h, 16))
```

or:

```
sorted(hex_list, key=lambda h: int(h, 16))
```

The `key` isn't a comparator (like in, say, Java); it's used to translate the items in the list directly into something that has the sorting semantics you're looking for.  In this case, it translates the hex strings into their int representations.

(Note that `hex` is a builtin function in Python, so you probably don't want to name your list that -- it's actually the exact inverse of our `key` function above, turning an `int` into its base-16 `str` representation.)

Comment: Nice! Didn't think it would be that easy, thanks! By the way whats the difference between `int(h, 16)` and `int(h, 0)`?

Comment: `16` specifies explicitly that you want to interpret the numbers as base-16, whereas `0` specifies that it should be inferred from the prefix (which makes the code a little harder to reason about IMO -- if you already know that it's base-16, better to just say that than telling the interpreter to try to guess at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do the work:

```
array = ['0x1', '0x2', '0x10', '0x7', '0x1a']

sorted = list(map(lambda v: int(v, 16), array))
sorted.sort()

result = []

for num in sorted:
  result.append(hex(num))
```

Comment: Note that [`sorted` is a built-in function in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), so it's not a good idea to use it as a variable name.

Comment: as the `hex` function